# Eclipse/Pydev I am having trouble creating a new module

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, createfile

this is two questions, really.  The two together may help diagnose.  When I select 
file>new>PyDev Module  I get a screen with the Source Folder and the Package  fields are blank.  When I click on the browse push button, I get the second screen which is blank with "no entries available".  If I manually enter the path to the source folder, I get the message: "The source folder was not found in the workspace"

The second possibly related problem is that the Pydev Package Explorer tab is blank.  Shouldn't it show the packages I have previously created?

Comment: I think you need to do that within a PyDev project.

Comment: Thank you.  Your hint got me to find out how to import an existing project into the workspace:
Use File > Import and select General > Existing Projects into Workspace. Click next and then browse to the directory contain the project directory.   Once I had done that the new file wizard worked .  Problem solved